Embedded widget loses it's options when c.server.update() is run
In ServiceNow portal, which uses Angular JS, I embed a widget within my own custom widget.
Server Script:
data.widget = $sp.getWidget('my-items', options);

And then HTML:
<sp-widget widget="data.widget"></sp-widget>

I send in the options, but for some reason, whenever the embedded widget runs it's own c.server.update(), it looses these options.
I wonder if this is a weakness in ServiceNow's sp-widget directive or if it can be avoided somehow.
I need the embedded widget to refresh it's data, and it has it's own c.asyncGet() function, which works! But it looses the parameters I sent in initially and reloads it's data as if I never sent in anything.
c.asyncGet() looks like this:
c.asyncGet = function() {
    c.data.action = "loadData";
    c.server.update().then(function(response) {
        fetchMyItemsData();
        if (c.data.card_behaviour == 'single') {
            resetCarousel();
        } else {
            adaptCardGrid();
        }
        handleTextOnlyZoom();
    });
};

And it's server script looks like this:
(function() {

    data.load_config = options.load_config;
    if (data.load_config === "async" && !input)
        return;
    data.card_behaviour = options.card_behaviour;

    try {
        data.recordLimit = options.list_view_count;
        data.showViewDetails = options.show_view_details;
        data.showIcons = options.show_icons;
        var activityConfigUtil = new sn_ex_sp.ActivityConfigurationUtil();
        data.activityDetails = activityConfigUtil.getActivityData(data.recordLimit);
        //Map actions with associated card
        for (var cardDataIndex = 0; cardDataIndex < data.activityDetails.listViewData.length; cardDataIndex++) {
            var currCardData = data.activityDetails.listViewData[cardDataIndex];
            currCardData.title = currCardData.title ? GlideStringUtil.unEscapeHTML(currCardData.title) : "";
            currCardData.description = currCardData.description ? GlideStringUtil.unEscapeHTML(currCardData.description) : "";
            currCardData.field1Value = currCardData.field1Value ? GlideStringUtil.unEscapeHTML(currCardData.field1Value) : "";
            currCardData.field2Value = currCardData.field2Value ? GlideStringUtil.unEscapeHTML(currCardData.field2Value) : "";
            if (currCardData.actionsWidgetDetail) {
                var context = currCardData.actionsWidgetDetail.parentRecordSysId;

                var actionsWidget = $sp.getWidget("action-widget", {
                    table: currCardData.actionsWidgetDetail.parentTable,
                    context: context,
                    action_group: currCardData.actionsWidgetDetail.actionGrpSysId,
                    max_button_count: 2,
                    primary_colored_button: true,
                    more_icon: 'fa-ellipsis-v'
                });

                currCardData.actionsWidget = actionsWidget;
                currCardData.actionsContext = context;
                currCardData.isActionWidgetVisible = true;
            }
        }

        data.title = gs.getMessage("My active items");

        if (data.activityDetails.listViewData && data.activityDetails.listViewData.length > 0) {

            var isSessionLangGerman = gs.getSession().getLanguage() == "de";
            var itemName = data.activityDetails.primaryCountData.length > 0 ? data.activityDetails.primaryCountData[0].itemName : undefined;
            //Nouns always start with capital letter in German
            itemName = isSessionLangGerman ? itemName : itemName.toLowerCase();

            data.listCountSummary = gs.getMessage("Showing {0} of {1} {2}",
                [data.activityDetails.listViewData.length.toString(),
                    data.activityDetails.primaryCountData[0].itemCount.toString(), itemName
                ]);
            data.noOfCards = data.activityDetails.listViewData.length;
        }
        data.hideWidget = false;
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        data.hideWidget = true;
        gs.addErrorMessage(gs.getMessage("Error in loading the My Items widget"));
        return data;
    }

})();

I COULD reinitialize the widget from my own custom widget instead of running c.asyncGet() in the first place. But when I do that, it doesn't re-render the view, even though the embedded widget's data does refresh and looks correct when I console.log() it.
Running $apply() doesn't seem to do much either.
